# Find all the planes that generate a specific angle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

I have to find all the planes that contain the straight line

$x-1 = y + 1 = z$

and that have and angle of $60deg$ with the plane

$ 2x + 4y -6z +9 = 0$

Correct Answer:

a) $2x - 3y + z - 5 = 0$

b) $3x - y -2z -4 = 0$

## ----------

For solve the problem

#### 1) I found the bundle of planes containing the straight line

$ x(A) + y(B-A) +z (-B) -2(A) + B = 0$

with director parameters

$ \vec n = ( A, B - A, -B )$

#### 2) I found the given plane director parameters

$\vec v = (2, 4, -6)$ that i transformed to $\vec v =(1, 2, -3)$

#### 3) I used the formula to calculate the angle between planes

$cos(t) =  {\vec v * \vec n\over||\vec n|| ||\vec v||} = cos(60deg)$

Solving this equation i arrived to

$2A^2 - 6B^2 + AB = 0$

I used B as constant with value $B=1$ and solved the equation using A as variable, doing so i found the vectors of the planes

$\vec q = (2, -1, -1), \vec w = (-3/2, 5/2, -1)$

that are wrong.

What am i missing?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand your approach. Do you mind if I suggest another elementary method?

Comment: Yeah sure go on

Comment: What is $A$ and $B$ in your attempt?

Comment: Are the parameters that let me identify the bundle of planes. if I have a straight line identified by a system of two equations ( so the cartesian form of a straight line ) the boundle of plane is: $A*(equation1) + B*(equation2) = 0$

Comment: Thanks! can you link some sources about that? In my book and on some sites i read that the angle between planes and normals is the same

Comment: By the way it tried it also with $cos(120deg)$ in the step 3 and i find the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After solving the problem myself, I discovered that the elementary method I was talking about is not that elementary and your's is the best one with a slight error.

Let the equation of plane passing through the point $(1,-1,0)$ be $A(x-1)+B(y+1)+Cz=0$. Now, the direction vector of the line is perpendicular to this plane. So, $A+B+C=0$. $$\therefore Ax+By+z(-A-B)+B-A=0\tag{1}$$ Now, after applying the condition of $60^\circ$, we get the quadratic as $3A^2+11AB+B^2=0$ $$\therefore A=-3B\;\text{or}\,A=-\frac{2}{3}B$$ Substitute this values in eq.$1$ and you get your answer.